# Api Gateway adding "localhost" to address on docker-compose

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to deploy SpringBoot microservices using `docker-compose` but I'm having a problem with API Gateway.

If I run the project locally it works ok, even if I deploy project using docker-compose but API Gateway locally, it works ok, so problem has to be "dockerizing" the API Gateway service.

Doing `docker logs <container>` it shows:

```
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: finishConnect(..) failed: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8083
```

Is obvious there is a problem on host `localhost/127.0.0.1`. Why Gateway is trying to point a "repeated" address?.

`docker-compose.yml` looks like this:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  # more services

  api-gateway:
    build: ./path_to_dockerfile
    depends_on:
        - eureka-server
    environment:
      - eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://eureka-server:8761/eureka/
    restart: always
    container_name: gateway
    ports:
        - '9000:9000'
```

Dockerfile is as simple as this

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
ADD target/apigateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

And `application.yml`:

```yaml
server:
  port: 9000

spring:
  application:
    name: Api-Gateway-Service

  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin, RETAIN_UNIQUE

      globalcors:
        # cors config

      routes:

        - id: <name>-microservice
          uri: http://localhost:8083

          predicates:
            - Path=/<path>/**
            - Method=GET,POST,DELETE,PUT,OPTIONS

        # more routes on different ports

eureka:
  # eureka config
```

So, why is adding "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" and calling twice?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8083` means that it was trying to add or call `localhost` twice. It is just the way it shows the error.

In your `application.yml`, try changing `uri` to the name you used for your microservice inside `docker-compose` file.

```
routes:

        - id: <name>-microservice
          uri: <YOUR_SERVICE_NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that docker doesn't support network communication between containers by default. You can connect to the 8083 port from your host but not another container. If so, you should create a network and contact the container and network.